# add sublist to list

Tags: java

```
   package com.pinchuk.problem_test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Sr{
    String value;
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listOfservices = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfservices.add(0,"первый сервисс");
        listOfservices.add(1,"2 сервисс");
        listOfservices.add(2,"3 сервисс");
        listOfservices.add(3,"4 сервисс");
        listOfservices.add(4,"5 сервисс");
        listOfservices.add(5,"6 сервисс");
        listOfservices.add(6,"7 сервисс");
        listOfservices.add(7,"8 сервисс");
        listOfservices.add(8,"9 сервисс");
        listOfservices.add(9,"10 сервисс");
    }
}
```

на входе есть 10 переменных по 3 параметра у каждой!Как их добавить в список?

Comment: реализовать что?

Comment: Уточните, как они "входят" - заданы в программе или вводятся? Если известно сколько их, то можно просто в массив записывать, а если нет, то можно ArrayList<>...

Comment: да они константы

Comment: В чём у вас проблема, что не получается? Опишите подробнее.

Comment: ну отдельно лист для 10 переменных я создал и отдельно интерфейс для 3 значений, как связать их, В конце нужно вывести нужную строку из этих 10ти на выбор с подкатегорией

Comment: Алгоритм выбора выводимой информации какой? И код бы добавили, чтобы яснее было.

Comment: Проблема в том что я не знаю за что взяться , я разбил задачу на несколько мелких, вот первая часть в вопросе

Comment: как я понял это что то типа лога, пользователь задает вопрос к одной из категорий в свою очередь у вопросов свои категории, и тоге на выходе в консоль строка  service_id [.variation_id] question_type_id [.category_id. [Подкатегория_ид]] P / N дата времени

Comment: Можно через List, можно через Set, можно через Map, можно просто через двухмерный массив. Как сами решите для своих задач.

Comment: @Kosmos а как связать лист с подкатегориями?

Comment: @ИгорьГор я не могу связать лист с подкатегориями.

Comment: Я пока вижу одномерный массив с пустой нулевой ячейкой. Задача, стоящая перед вами, мне по-прежнему не ясна. Извините.

Comment: @ИгорьГор задача в том что бы обьявить 10 переменных у которых по 3 свойства у каждой! и то и то константы

Comment: Ну, создайте класс с тремя "свойствами", а потом десять объектов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```
public void listWithSublist(){
    List<List<Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        List<Object> subList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
            subList.add(j);
        }
        list.add(subList);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.print("List " + (i+1) + " contains: ");
        for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).toArray().length; j++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + list.get(i).get(j));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: о боже) да спасибо)

Comment: да не за что :)